# Hair Mesh keeps deforming incorrectly

Tags: mesh

[image: This is what it looks like untouched]

[image: This is when it gets moved]

I parented the hair to a single bone via vertex groups and I've tried a few other ways but the hair always deforms oddly. Automatic weights makes it worse.

The Hair was imported from FBX if that matters.

The blend file is 150mb so I will have to cut out a few other meshes if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mesh was imported as FBX export to OBJ then import new OBJ mesh into blender file.